# How to round numbers to its 0.5 superior in python

Tags: logic

So basically my question is if i have for example 2.2 i need to create a python function to round numers to its higher 0.5 part, i mean
2.2 --> 2.5
2.3 --> 2.5
2.5 --> 2.5
2.6 --> 3
I cant use anything but maths operators
( +, *, **, //, %, - )

Comment: Please don't delete your question after you've received an answer.  That can be considered impolite to the answerer.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of knowledge, through high-quality questions and answers that will be useful to others in the future.  People may be answering on that basis, and deleting your question after receiving an answer is contrary to those goals.

Comment: For future reference, questions about how to code something in Python are normally considered off-topic here.  See our [help/on-topic].

Comment: Although finding a way to round the number as requested with only the listed operators is a nice language-agnostic puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to count in halves instead of units, i.e., double double the original number, round it the next integer, and finally divide back by $2$.

Rounding a number $x$ down previous integer using only the listed operators is quite easy: just use the integer division by $1$, i.e., `x//1`.

Rounding $x$ to the next integer is a bit more annoying (notice that you can't just add $1$ to `x//1`). What we can do is inverting x, rounding down, and then inverting the result again.

Putting all together: `-((-2*x)//1)/2`